# Double regex necessary?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use regex to parse urls.

The format of the urls can be like this

yadayadahttp://www.theurl.com/apage
yadayadahttp://www.theurl.com/
yadayadahttp://www.theurl.com
yadayadahttp://meow.theurl.com/apage
yadayadahttp://theurl.com
yadayadahttp://theurl.com/

These are my two regex to handle both with and without www(or any other subdoamin).

The www regex:

```
    \bhttp:\/\/\b\w*[a-z0-9]\.\w*[a-z0-9]\.\w*[a-z0-9]
```

and the non www regex:

```
    \bhttp:\/\/\b\w*[a-z0-9]\.\w*[a-z0-9]
```

Is there anyway to combine them? I know there is but I can't seem to do it. I have tried for a couple of hours now.

Also they seem to return empty matches which gives my list unecessary items, is it possible to return matches that are not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work for you..

```
\bhttp:\/\/(\b\w*[a-z0-9]\.)?\w*[a-z0-9]\.\w*[a-z0-9]
```

Comment: Raw Match Pattern:
\bhttp:\/\/(\b\w*[a-z0-9]\.)?\w*[a-z0-9]\.\w*[a-z0-9]

at http://myregextester.com/index.php

Matches Found:
NO MATCHES.

Comment: @CarlPalsson :: what was the source text?

Comment: The strings above
yadayadahttp://www.theurl.com/apage
yadayadahttp://www.theurl.com/
yadayadahttp://www.theurl.com
yadayadahttp://meow.theurl.com/apage
yadayadahttp://theurl.com
yadayadahttp://theurl.com/

Comment: @CarlPalsson :: then you may try like this `\b(\w*[a-z0-9])?http:\/\/(\b\w*[a-z0-9]\.)?\w*[a-z0-9]\.\w*[a-z0-9]`

Answer (score 0):

The following might do it:

```
\bhttp:\/\/([\w\d\-\.]+\.)?[\w\d\-\.]+\.[\w\d]+\/?
```